# How to create dynamic urls in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

In Google Slides, text or images can be hyperlinked. I want to embed variables in the document i.e {{first_name}} into an url i.e http://sample.com/1235?person-name={{first_name}}. I've tried and failed to make this work, but wonder if anyone else has had success. If so, I would be grateful for your guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may import object(as excel file) with in your presentation.

Comment: That's true but not relevant to the question.